# Plotly (r): Can values in a drop-down box change automatically to reflect data-frame changes?

Tags: r, drop-down-menu, plotly

I am investigating using interactive `plotly` graphs that allow for the selection of categorical values, which change the plot accordingly. I am planning on using the following code structure that has been used in an example with the 'iris' database in `R`.

However, this code seems to require hardcoding in the amount of categorical variables in the drop-down list (in this example, there are 3 species of which 3 lists have been created to reflect this).

Thus my question is, if the database changed over time with an increase in the number of categorical variables, which would need to be included in the drop-down list, is there a way to automatically update the drop-down list values without having to hardcode them in?
Thank you for your time.

```
library(plotly)    
p <- iris %>%
  plot_ly(
    type = 'scatter', 
    x = ~Sepal.Length, 
    y = ~Petal.Length,
    text = ~Species,
    hoverinfo = 'text',
    mode = 'markers', 
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter',
        target = ~Species,
        operation = '=',
        value = unique(iris$Species)[1]
      )
    )) %>% layout(
      updatemenus = list(
        list(
          type = 'dropdown',
          active = 0,
          buttons = list(
            **list**(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[1]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[1]),
            **list**(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[2]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[2]),
            **list**(method = "restyle",
                 args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(iris$Species)[3]),
                 label = unique(iris$Species)[3])
          )
        )
      )
    )
p
```